# Trig: Even and Odd Functions

Tags: trigonometry

Why is it that:

$$\sin^2(-x) = \sin^2(x) $$

And:

$$\sec^2(-x) = \sec^2(x)$$

Would the same hold true if the exponent was a $3$ or a $5$? How come the same isn't applicable to sin or the other trigonometric functions?

Comment: Hint: odd powers of an odd function are odd, even powers of an odd function are even.

Comment: Keep in mind that a function (trigonometric or otherwise) is *called* "even" (or "odd") precisely because its effect on sign matches that of an even (respectively, odd) exponent. Thus, so far as sign issues are concerned, an even-or-odd power of an even-or-odd function behaves like an even-or-odd power of an even-or-odd power.

Answer (score 1):

Because Sine is an odd function, we have that $\sin(-x)^2 = (-\sin x)^2 = (-1)^2 \sin(x)^2 = \sin(x)^2$

Similar logic yields your second identity

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if suppose $f(x)$ is an even function then $f(x) = f(-x)$,

so $f^{n}(x) = f^{n}(-x)$

and now suppose that $g(x)$ is an odd function

so $g(-x) = -g(x)$

Hence when we take the power (composition) that is $g^{n}(-x) = (-1)^{n}g^{n}(x)$ and thus now the equality between the two is obtained depending upon whether $n$ is odd or even.

If $n$ is even then $g^{n}(-x) = (-1)^{n}g^{n}(x) = g^{n}(x)$ 
and

for the case of odd $n$,we get $g^{n}(-x) = (-1)^{n}g^{n}(x) = - g^{n}(x)$.

Coming to Trigonometric functions we know $\sin(x)$ is an odd function,and $\cos(x)$ is an even functions and you can apply the above theory now and check for any power now!.